# change nslayoutconstraint programmatically auto refresh

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

In the storyboard this constraint is active:

```
@IBOutlet weak var priceConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I set `isActive` property to be `false` (programmatically), like this:

```
self.priceConstraint.isActive = false  

self.priceLabel.setNeedsLayout()     
self.priceLabel.layoutIfNeeded()           
self.priceLabel.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

after a few seconds it becomes active again, why? how can I avoid that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why my constrain change alone ? how can I avoid that?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly about **change alone**?

Comment: Are you sure that there is nothing happened to re-active it again? Also, is there a case that needs to re-active it again?

Comment: yes they are a case to active it again but the func isn't call

Comment: **Change alone** is the constains did become active again without refresh of view or action in the code.

Comment: @user3333632 I tried with you code and the constraint didn't become active again. I think you made it re-active somewhere in your code.

Comment: i just detect that after few seconds, sometimes the function viewWillLayoutSubviews is called again. It's after the constrain become active.

Comment: where do you call this function?